# How do I click on an <a> HTML element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was attempting to click on an element of a webpage that looked something like this:

```
<div class="a_class">
   <a id="an_id" class="class2">
      <span>Text</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

I already tried using `document.getElementById("an_id").click();` and it returns telling me it is undefined. Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: If it says that `document.getElementById("an_id")` is undefined then it means that it's not finding the element. Are you executing the code after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: use the javascript event onClick. You can place it in any tag. <span onClick=> </span>